# Margin от <p>заходит на тег <a/>

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: Иллюстрация проблемы]

```css
body{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
p{
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16pt;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{
    font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.btn{
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 900;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #ffd429;
    padding:  24px 28px;

    box-sizing: border-box !important;

}
.container{
    padding:0 376px ;
}



#header{/*здесь я обращаюсь по id т.к. на странице могут быть другие элементы со своим header*/
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( 121deg, rgb(55,143,217) 0%, rgb(78,190,254) 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( 121deg, rgb(55,143,217) 0%, rgb(78,190,254) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( 121deg, rgb(55,143,217) 0%, rgb(78,190,254) 100%);
    color: #fff;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.headerContainer{
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.offer{
    margin-top: 90px;
    width: 565px;
}
h1{
    margin-bottom: 45px;
    font-size: 32px;
}
.fontSize_59pt{
    font-size: 50px;
}
.offer p{
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Дз 4</title>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link
        href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@900&family=Open+Sans&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;700&display=swap"
        rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">

</head>

<body>
    <header class="header container" id="header">
        <img src="./img/logo.png" alt="WAYUP">
        <div class="headerContainer">
            <div class="offer">
                <h1>
                    С помощью верстки<br>
                    я создам ту жизнь, о которой<br>
                    <span class="fontSize_59pt"> мечтаю!</span>
                </h1>
                <p>
                    Мои стремления + настойчивость позволят мне <br>
                    достичь чего угодно. Я не верю в это. Я знаю это <br>
                    на 100%. Меня не остановить!
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn">Двигаться к мечте</a>
            </div>
            <img src="./img/header_img.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="section container"></section>
    <section class="section container"></section>
    <footer class="footer" id="footer"></footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: сделайте для кнопки ```display: inline-block;```

Comment: можешь для кнопки написать `display: inline-block; position: absolute`, а для `#header` прописать `paddint-bottom: 24px;`, в принципе сядет нормально

Comment: Первый коммент тру ответ

Comment: вы пишите это ответами

Comment: как мне теперь закрыть вопрос?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделайте для кнопки

```
display: inline-block;
```

Этот ответ верный, сделан soledar10

[профиль soledbar10](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/13968/soledar10)